# How to hide UINavigationBar and UITabBar animated?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have a `UIViewController` with `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. I want to hide them animated: `UINavigationBar` flip upward and `UITabBar` flip downward. During the animation, I need the `UIViewController`'s view resizing automatically to fulfil the new frame.

How to do it?

**My structure is:** `UIViewController` is placed in a `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController`, and the `UINavigationControlle`r is placed in a `UITabBarController` as a `childViewController`.

I have tried resize the `AppDelegate.window.frame` directly but it will make other views.frame incorrect.

Comment: Is your `UIViewController` placed inside a `UINavigationController` or can you elaborate further about your structure?

Answer (score 3):

Since **iOS8** you can use:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

**INFO**

There is a bunch of nice new methods since iOS8:

`UINavigationController`

`hidesBarsOnTap`: A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation controller allows hiding of its bars using a tap gesture.

`hidesBarsOnSwipe`: A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation bar hides its bars in response to a swipe gesture.

`hidesBarsWhenVerticallyCompact`: A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation controller hides its bars in a vertically compact environment.

`hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears`: A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation controller hides its bars when the keyboard appears.